# SPO 2013 - Hashtag "Profile pages" and trending hashtags are both empty

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, social, office-365, hashtags

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013.

We can type in hashtags successfully in our discussion forum (community site), which is a subsite of our root site. We can also follow the hashtags that are typed in there. Also in our personal NewsFeeds we can see when our followed hashtags are used.

However if we click a hashtag, it will lead to the "Hashtag profile page" where one could see related discussions etc. but no related discussions can be found there. In other words, the "Hashtag profile pages" are empty. Also the trending hashtags in users' NewsFeeds are empty as well.

I have not modified the hashtag settings in the Admin center in any way so it should be in its default state.

I hope someone can help me find answers and a solution for this problem!

**EDIT:** Also when trying to query hashtag from the hashtag's profile page, the search does not return any results. :/

**EDIT 2:** The Tag Cloud web part does not show any hashtags either.

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing and troubleshooting the problem got solved with assistance of Microsoft's customer support.

It appears there was a quite big problem which was the cause. Now it is fixed and as a result we can now see trending hashtags and related conversations but only from the Newsfeed "Everyone" posts. So if someone uses a hashtag in our community sub site discussion area the posts and used hashtags will not show in the hashtag profiles or in the trending hashtags.

No idea why but it seems to be like this by design. Just wanted to get this out here if someone else is seeking the same information. :-)

Comment: It seems this is by design:  

"I called Microsoft support and they confirmed that "Hashtag Profile" only shows Related conversations that originated on user's Mysites newsfeed. They do not show related conversations from Community site discussions."

>> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fc12c8fe-ab27-4d52-8e41-b03898cd4757/hashtag-profile-page-does-not-show-activity?forum=sharepointdevelopment&prof=required